# Weird JavaScript arithmetic behavior for random number in different browsers, possible arithmetic precision issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Can someone explain the logic behind why the chrome and firefox engines do below arithmetic differently than IE? Below is a snap from firefox console.

[Screenshot from browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFNjz.jpg)

```js
console.log('(26.6811*1000/1000) = ' + (26.6811 * 1000 / 1000));
console.log('(26.6821*1000/1000) = ' + (6.6821 * 1000 / 1000));
console.log('(26.6721*1000/1000) = ' + (26.6721 * 1000 / 1000));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: @rmlan The behavior is different in IE compared to Chrome and Mozilla